# Alternative of @RequestBody

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

Is there an alternative way to obtain a reference to a request's body without using the approach with the annotation? I'm using `GAE + Spring` and everytime I use `@RequestBody` in the signatures of my controller methods, the server returns `415 Unsupported Media Type`. All I'm trying to do is read a `JSON encoded message` on a Post method. Thanks.

Comment: What about fixing the media type to the correct type?  Most likely need to tweak the message converters.

Comment: Hey I've tried that but it made no difference, thanks anyway.

Comment: What is GAE sending the media type in as? I know that sometimes the headers can get tweaked, you may want to do the below and log the media type inbound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take in a parameter of `HttpServletRequest`, and read the `ServletInputStream` using [`getInputStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream%28%29) from there.  The stream will contain the body of the request.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String aTest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        InputStream body = request.getInputStream();
        //process request body
        return myReturnVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, on the RequestMapping configure the headers to accept application/json and be sure to configure a jackson message convertor for this type