# How to unmarshall to different @RequestBody object types?

Tags: web-services, spring, spring-mvc, unmarshalling

I'm using Spring in my web service which receives XML as input. It can be XML embebed in the HTTP request or as a plain text in the *request* attribute.

Currently my web service is handling two different XML schemas so my unmarshaller can unmarshall the XML files to two object types (for example: Foo and Bar).

In my Controller, I have the next code to handler the *request* attribute:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/mypath"}, method={RequestMethod.POST}, headers={"content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseObject getResponse(@RequestParam("request") String request, HttpServletRequest req) {
```

It works perfectly, with the request string I can unmarshall to Foo object or Bar object.

The problem comes with the XML embebed:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/mypath"}, method={RequestMethod.POST}, headers={"content-type=text/xml"})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseObject getResponse(@RequestBody Foo request, HttpServletRequest req) {
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/mypath"}, method={RequestMethod.POST}, headers={"content-type=text/xml"})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseObject getResponse(@RequestBody Bar request, HttpServletRequest req) {
```

and here is the MessageConverter:

```
<bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
</bean>
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="jaxb2Marshaller" contextPath="path.to.Foo:path.to.Bar"/>
```

I think that the MessageConverter should do the unmarshall automagically but I receive the next error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path '/ws/mypath.ws': [...] If you intend to handle the same path in multiple methods, then factor them out into a dedicated handler class with that path mapped at the type level!

How can I unmarshall automatically to different `@RequestBody` object types? (with the same *web service path*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has to be something in the `@RequestMapping` which makes each request method unique, in your case both the xml based request mappings exactly the same - the type of the parameters is figured out after the framework has found the correct method with the `@RequestMapping`. So essentially what you are saying is not feasible unless you have something more in the annotation to help the framework with finding the correct method.

One small simplification that you can make is the following, if you are on Spring 3.1+:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/mypath"}, method={RequestMethod.POST}, consumes=text/xml)
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for your clarification. I can't have two different `@RequestMapping` in this case, so I'll have to change my approach here. I think the best way to "solve" this is [using the HttpServletRequest object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476372/alternative-of-requestbody) to get the input stream, but I'm loosing the unmarshall automagically functionallity.